# Reusing killed spawn process

Tags: multiprocessing, daemon, tracking, spawn, dlib

I am trying to use multiprocessing for tracking different objects in a stream of video. Every time, if object is detected, it passes on the value to tracker which goes into separate spawn daemonic process. At any concurrent time, no more than 5 processes are running, but I want to reuse my killed processes even for tracking new objects. Can anyone explain how to do it?

P.S not using pool because control over each process is necessary to evaluate further.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed this using,

delete(Pool) or delete(Process) after closing & joining.